# have a small problem in use of dd

Tags: dd

I have a small problem in use of dd, actually I read this topic:
[How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)
and I cannot understand some things,Now my question is: whats the meaning of "bs=X" and "&& synce" in dd?

Comment: IIRC bs=`block size` when reading and writing from same drive a higher block size will reduce disk thrashing, ie constant head seeking, reading, seeking and writing. In your case `if` and `of` are different drives so it's a mute point I think. Default is `512` but some recommend `32MB`. As for `sync` - related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706670/why-is-the-sync-option-used-with-the-dd-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man dd`, with many more options avalable:

> bs=BYTES
>
> ```
>          read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
> ```

You'd usually use Mega Bytes, for example `bs=4M` or `bs=4096`.

`&& sync` is there to flush buffers after dd is finished.